# Un-configured MIME types hangs up publisher

Tags: 2011, dd4t

Whenever some of the unconfigured MIME types are sent for publishing our publisher is hanging up and someone has to manually kill the process to get it running.

To get rid of this, I am trying to understand DD4T and want to know how to fix this. Currently we are using ECL library for resolving multimedia items from an external asset management system. We either need to fail publishing or publishing should succeed rather than hanging up the publisher.

Update:

Below is the code I have updated. I have hard coded variant ID for the time being. Still the publisher is hanging up. Am i missing something?

```
protected virtual void PublishItem(Item item, TcmUri itemUri, out int ImageWidth, out int ImageHeight)
        {

            ImageWidth = 0;
            ImageHeight = 0;
            Stream itemStream = null;
            // See if some template set itself as the applied template on this item
            TcmUri appliedTemplateUri = null;
            if (item.Properties.ContainsKey(Item.ItemPropertyTemplateUri))
            {
                appliedTemplateUri = new TcmUri(item.Properties[Item.ItemPropertyTemplateUri]);
            }

            try
            {
                string publishedPath;
                if (targetStructureGroupUri == null)
                {
                    log.Debug("no structure group defined, publishing binary with default settings");
                    Component mmComp = (Component)engine.GetObject(item.Properties[Item.ItemPropertyTcmUri]);
                    // Note: it is dangerous to specify the CT URI as variant ID without a structure group, because it will fail if you publish the same MMC from two or more CTs!
                    // So I removed the variant ID altogether (QS, 20-10-2011)
                    log.Debug(string.Format("publishing mm component {0} without variant id", mmComp.Id));
                    //Binary binary = engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(mmComp);

                    string fileName = ConstructFileName(mmComp, currentTemplate.Id);
                    using (Stream stream = CreateTemperaryFileStream())
                    {
                        item.GetAsStream().CopyTo(stream);
                        Binary binary = engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(stream, fileName, "1024X1024", mmComp, mmComp.BinaryContent.MultimediaType.MimeType);
                        publishedPath = binary.Url;
                    }
                    log.Debug(string.Format("binary is published to url {0}", publishedPath));
                }
                else
                {
                    Component mmComp = (Component)engine.GetObject(item.Properties[Item.ItemPropertyTcmUri]);

                    string fileName = ConstructFileName(mmComp, currentTemplate.Id);
                    StructureGroup targetSG = (StructureGroup)engine.GetObject(targetStructureGroupUri);
                    itemStream = item.GetAsStream();
                    if (itemStream == null)
                    {
                        // All items can be converted to a stream?
                        log.Error(String.Format("Cannot get item '{0}' as stream", itemUri.ToString()));
                    }
                    //byte[] data = new byte[itemStream.Length];
                    //itemStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    //itemStream.Close();
                    log.Debug(string.Format("publishing mm component {0} to structure group {1} with variant id {2} and filename {3}", mmComp.Id, targetStructureGroupUri.ToString(), currentTemplate.Id, fileName));
                    //Binary b = engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(item.GetAsStream(), fileName, targetSG, currentTemplate.Id, mmComp, mmComp.BinaryContent.MultimediaType.MimeType);

                    //publishedPath = engine.AddBinary(itemUri, appliedTemplateUri, targetStructureGroupUri, data, fileName);
                    using (Stream stream = CreateTemperaryFileStream())
                    {

                        itemStream.CopyTo(stream);

                        Binary b = engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(stream, fileName, targetSG,
                                                                                           currentTemplate.Id, mmComp,
                                                                                           mmComp.BinaryContent
                                                                                                 .MultimediaType
                                                                                                 .MimeType);
                        publishedPath = b.Url;
                    }

                    log.Debug(string.Format("binary is published to url {0}", publishedPath));
                }
                log.Debug("binary published, published path = " + publishedPath);
                item.Properties[Item.ItemPropertyPublishedPath] = publishedPath;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (itemStream != null) itemStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on unconfigured MIME types, do you mean they are not known MIME types for SDL Tridion or something else? Also how are you handling the ECL items, is Tridion Publishing them using the `AddBinary()` method, or are they just resolved to a direct link or template fragment?

Comment: They are not known MIME types for tridion and you are right they are published using AddBinary() method.

Comment: Are you using the standard DD4T template building blocks, like Generate Dynamic Page/Component, Add binaries for Page/Component? Or did you create your own TBBs?

Comment: @Kris so you are calling `IContentLibraryMultimediaItem.GetContent()`, could it be that the content stream is just incredibly large and the Publisher isn't really hanging but getting a lot of data? Last week my [Resolve ECL Items TBB](https://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/source/browse/ECL%20TBB/trunk/ECL%20Template%20Building%20Blocks/ResolveEclItems.cs) was changed to save the stream to a file temporarily for performance reasons, see the `CreateTemporaryFileStream()` method.

Comment: @Quirijn I have customized generate dynamic page\component and binary publisher code but finally we are calling PublishMultimediaComponent() method of BinaryPublisher class.

Comment: @BartKoopman If this issue is with the data being large then i always get the issue with tif files rather than any other files like jpeg or png which are huge. Only tif is unconfigured so probably i am feeling it is something else.

Comment: @Kris I would definitely try using the code from the [`CreateTemporaryFileStream()`](https://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/source/browse/ECL%20TBB/trunk/ECL%20Template%20Building%20Blocks/ResolveEclItems.cs#1013) method, it will improve performance and might fix your issue. Else there is something else going wrong, the Tridion Publisher should be able to publish a .tif file, although I have to say I never did that before.

Comment: @BartKoopman will give it a try and will share the results

Comment: I have used the temporaryfilestream and it did not solve my issue. Is there any significance of IContentLibraryMultimediaItem.GetContent()as i dont see it being used anywhere. Instead the multimediacomp uri is passed directly to PublishItem method

Comment: @Quirijn Does publishing of unconfigured mime such as TIF works with BinaryPublisher.cs file? I am asking this as i am highly confused on how to fix this up.

Comment: Please see my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CreateTemperaryFileStream() solved the issue with a bit of changes in size limits in web config of HTTP upload and deployer config file. Thanks to Bart & Quirijn.

Answer (score 0):

An ECL multimedia component is only a stub. It does not give access to the actual content. You will need to call the ECL api. The following code could serve as a starting point. I haven't tested this, don't even know for sure if it will compile. You have been warned :)

```
    protected override void PublishItem(Item item, TcmUri itemUri)
    {
        IEclSession eclSession = SessionFactory.CreateEclSession(engine.GetSession());
        IEclUri eclUri = TryGetEclUriFromTcmUri(itemUri);
        if (eclUri != null)
        {
            IContentLibraryContext eclContext = eclUri.GetContentLibrary(eclUri);
            IContentLibraryMultimediaItem eclItem = eclContext.GetItem(eclUri) as IContentLibraryMultimediaItem;
            IContentResult result = eclItem.GetContent(null); // assuming we don't need to pass in any template attributes
            Stream itemStream = result.Stream;
            if (itemStream == null)
            {
                log.Error(String.Format("Cannot get item '{0}' as stream", itemUri.ToString()));
                return;
            }
            log.Debug(string.Format("publishing mm component {0} to structure group {1} with variant id {2} and filename {3}", mmComp.Id, targetStructureGroupUri.ToString(), currentTemplate.Id, fileName));

            Component mmComp = (Component)engine.GetObject(item.Properties[Item.ItemPropertyTcmUri]);
            string fileName = ConstructFileName(mmComp, currentTemplate.Id);
            StructureGroup targetSG = (StructureGroup)engine.GetObject(targetStructureGroupUri);
            Binary b = engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(itemStream, fileName, targetSG,
                                                                                   currentTemplate.Id, mmComp,
                                                                                   mmComp.BinaryContent
                                                                                         .MultimediaType
                                                                                         .MimeType);
            publishedPath = b.Url;
            return;
         }
        // this is not an ECL item, continue normally

    }
```